# Play url video with MPMoviePlayerController without direct link

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a trouble with this problem:

- I have a video link (abc.com/video=x716a ) , but this link is not direct such as: */video.mp4.
- If i access this video link by browser, the video will be downloaded.

So now i use MPMoviePlayerController to play, it doesn't work. Please help me!

Thanks!